# Allow users to upload videos to my youtube channel without login

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

I have selected Application type "other and web application" while creating separate projects in Youtube developer console and using following code.

```
$scope = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setAccessToken('ya29.GlyKBK9LdtYRLNDYUdhXlhTiY_d51nLUZrIdikYoRY3M_5YQOpt5Pkx-uJ1RYpsvPOKyf4hTNBhKwOJ_fEncTURyNBeZa9ISRoVAmcuFaAlI_YgcQAs97GCbHklvXg');
$client->setScopes($scope);

$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

// Check if an auth token exists for the required scopes
$tokenSessionKey = 'token-' . $client->prepareScopes();
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  if (strval($_SESSION['state']) !== strval($_GET['state'])) {
    die('The session state did not match.');
  }

  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: ' . $redirect);
}

if (isset($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION[$tokenSessionKey]);
}
```

But it always give following error.

> A service error occurred: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain":
>   "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials",
>   "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code":
>   401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }

I am not getting what I am doing wrong and what could be the possible fix for this?

Comment: "Invalid credentials" doesn't mean anything to you?

Comment: But I am adding correct credentials, I have created project and from there I am adding client id and secret then generated access token I am passing